# Splitting a power supply to two monitors

Tags: power, monitor

I'm working on a project that requires 2 (identical) LED monitors, each of which has a separate power supply that outputs 19V 1.3A. To save space, I would like to instead use a single power supply with the same voltage, but more amperage (3.4A in this case), and use a basic Y-cable to split the output to individual monitors. Is this something that can be done, or would I need to build additional circuitry to split power output?

Also, at some point I plan to add a relay, so that one of the monitors can be turned on and off. Would that change the situation at all (i.e. require any additional changes?).

Comment: that should work just fine

Comment: LCD monitors are typically slow to react to power coming back on. but other than that the relay is unlikely to cause any problems.